# How do I debug my *Outlook* add-in? What exactly opens port 9222?

Tags: outlook, office-js, visual-studio-debugging

I've exactly followed these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-with-vs-extension
including rebooting several times, and also trying outlook.com website in both chrome and edge; Version 92.0.902.62 (Official build) (64-bit)

My add-in loads and works in in all of those, and my task pane opens no problem, however, at no time does *anything* open a port 9222, and I get the dreaded **outlook add-in error processing "attach" connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222** when I hit F5 in Visual Studio.

[ECONNREFUSED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG7r2.png)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -ab

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
  CDPSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
  EventLog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49669          DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
 [spoolsv.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49670          DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3000         DESKTOP-PHTG3OP:0      LISTENING
 [node.exe]
```

How are we supposed to get Outlook running in a way that port 9222 opens?  What *exactly* is responsible for even opening that port ?  (Outlook?  Some browser component of outlook?  Something in my actual task pane itself???)

Any/all help/suggestions **greatly** appreciated!!!

Comment: Update: since about May, when Microsoft removed "EdgeHTML" and replaced it with the "EdgeChromium" engine, it looks like all debugging tools have stopped working.  My **guess** is that the old, now-removed, "EdgeHTML" engine was the thing that opened port 9222 (and no longer does anymore, since it's gone).

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am stuck in the same place.